# The reason why?

Tags: riddle

I am why the sky is blue

And why we sleep at night.

I am why soap cleans your face

And sliced onions make you cry,

I am why your ice cubes float

And coffee keeps you sharp

But most of all I am why

Food tastes so good

And why love feels oh so fine.

Answer (score 4):

> I am Hydrogen (H)

I am why the sky is blue

> Sunlight collision with the air molecules in our atmosphere. The air is compound by other molecules and H2
>  http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/General/BlueSky/blue_sky.html

And why we sleep at night.

> Melatonin (C13H16N2O2)
>  https://www.webmd.com/sleep-disorders/tc/melatonin-overview

I am why soap cleans your face

> http://www.worldofmolecules.com/interactive_molecules/soap.htm

And sliced onions make you cry

> Sulfuric acid (H2SO4)
>  https://www.thoughtco.com/why-do-onions-make-you-cry-604309

I am why your ice cubes float

> Hydrogen bonds in water (H2O)
>  https://wonderopolis.org/wonder/why-does-ice-float-in-water

And coffee keeps you sharp

> Caffeine (C8H10N4O2)

But most of all I am why

> The most abundant element in the universe is hydrogen
>  https://www.livescience.com/28466-hydrogen.html

Food tastes so good

> Hydrogen ions
>  https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/a-simple-sourness-detector/

And why love feels oh so fine.

> Oxytocin (C43H66N12O12S2)
>  https://io9.gizmodo.com/5925206/10-reasons-why-oxytocin-is-the-most-amazing-molecule-in-the-world

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Why don't you take the [tour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour) and earn another badge?

Comment: Providing links to relevant information is fine, but you should include a summary of what that link says within the answer itself rather than just linking to it. See [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) which covers why: links can go dead, or their content changed, and at best it's distracting having to go elsewhere to see what information you were trying to share.

Comment: @Elvio Martinelli  What Rubio said.  I hate to accept or otherwise respond to an answer if the answer isn't really an answer.  Links are a big turn off in terms of representing the core of an answer.  So....give it some editing and personal 'opinionating' and I will have another look